# how to truncate a string from both ends if my string is very large?

Tags: c, string

I am trying to truncate a string from both ends and by theory I done this:

```
char *str = "this is string";
char a = 'a' ; // just to work with sizeof() function
str = str + 2*sizeof(a); // to truncate from left side 
printf("%s",str);
```

this prints `is is string`
but whan I add these lines to code

```
len = strlen(str);
str [len - 2] = '\0'; // to truncate from right side
```

I have also tried `*(str + len - 2) = 0;`
even `strcpy()` also not working

this returns `segmentation fault`

Please help to solve this issue and please let me know any other approach to do this.

Comment: You can "truncate" the string literal from the left by advancing a pointer, but you cannot truncate it from the right with a nul terminator, because it is read-only. You need to copy the string first, or extract characters in a way that does not mutate the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane didn't get that any article link and  `strncpy()` also didn't worked for me

Comment: `strncpy` might not add a nul terminator to the target. You can add it yourself.

Comment: @SachinMirajkar Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. You may truncate a string  contained in a user-defined character array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow as per my knowledge string is char array ending with `"\0"` then I am just doing the same thing theoretically

Comment: @SachinMirajkar As I said you may not change a string literal.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am trying to add the null char at the end that's what the question started with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LARGE_ENOUGH 100
 
int main(void) {
    char *basestring = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char dst[LARGE_ENOUGH] = "";
    int start = 3;
    int end = -4; // alternatively int length = 19;
    int length = strlen(basestring) - start + end;
    printf("middle(%d, %d): [%.*s]\n", start, end, length, basestring + start);

    sprintf(dst, "[%.*s]", length, basestring + start);
    printf("new string: %s\n", dst);

    return 0;
}
```

See https://ideone.com/Zvf5aW

Comment: how can I copy it to some other string ? I tried `sprintf(str,"[%.*s]",basestring + start);` didn't worked

Comment: You missed the length part (associated with the `*`): `sprintf(dst, "[%.*s]", length, basestring + start);`

Comment: Is that worked for you cuz it didn't worked for me, I am getting `segmentation fault`

Comment: Yes, that works for me. Note `dst` is a **proper array**, not a pointer. You can see this fork: https://ideone.com/JD2iKk , incorporated into my answer.

Comment: this worked thanks. what i was doing wrong is i had declared a char array `char *dest ="";` So when I changed it to `char dest[100];` it worked fine

Comment: This `char *dest` **is not**, I repeat **is not** an array!! You may like section 6 of the [comp.lang.c faq](http://c-faq.com/)

Comment: Just in case `LARGE_ENOUGH` is not large enough... you should use `snprintf()`: `snprintf(dst, sizeof dst, "%.*s", length, basestring + start);` or better use `strndup()`:  `char *dst = strndup(basestring + start, length);` You should also check that `start <= strlen(basestring)` and `start - end <= strlen(basestring)` and return an empty string otherwise.